# Failure in importing a list of lists

Tags: list-manipulation, export, import

I am importing data which are formatted as a list containing lists. And I would like to keep these data in this format.

```
Export["data.dat",{{1,{1,2,3}},{2,{3,4,5}}]
data=Import["data.dat"]
```

However, if I simply do that, *Mathematica* seems to consider the lists inside the list as strings so I tried:

```
data=ToExpression[Import["data.dat"]]
```

In this case Mathematica fails and gives the following error:

```
ToExpression::sntxi: Incomplete expression; more input is needed .
ToExpression::sntx: Invalid syntax in or before "2, ".
```

Actually doing some manipulations I realized that when you just import the list into Mathematica, it takes:

```
{{1, "{1,", "2,", "3}"}, {2, "{3,", "4,", "5}"}}
```

Any idea on how to convert this strange expression into the list I initially had?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to export to a .dat file if are going to read the file back into Mathematica. Better to use the extension .m for in that case.

```
path = FileNameJoin[{$HomeDirectory, "Desktop", "data.m"}]
Export[path, {{1, {1, 2, 3}}, {2, {3, 4, 5}}}];

data = Import[path]
```

> `{{1, {1, 2, 3}}, {2, {3, 4, 5}}}`

But this can be done more easily with

```
Put[{{1, {1, 2, 3}}, {2, {3, 4, 5}}}, path]
Get[path]
```

> `{{1, {1, 2, 3}}, {2, {3, 4, 5}}}`

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much :)